# How to save php errors in database?

Tags: php

I don't want to display errors in a screen, except that I want to save it in DB.
I can't find any information about it. I think that it isn't difficult task, I just can't imagine how to orginize that...

Thank you a lot!

Comment: Rather than handling this with PHP, look into your web server's database logging facility. Any errors going on screen are also in your error log.  Apache, for instance, has `mod_log_sql`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `set_error_handler('myErrorFunction');` (See [PHP Manual set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)) define `myErrorFunction` with database inserts, turn off standard error reporting display with `ini_get('display_errors', 0);`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to set_error_handler(), which is the right answer, you can use normal logical operators to detect things that you think might fail.  For example, it's common practice to use things like:

```
$h = @mysql_connect(...) or die();
```

You can similarly react to other failures with your own function instead of die().  The @ in front of the function tells it to be "silent" on errors.

Of course, if you're storing errors in a db, what happens if you can't talk to the db?  :)